# how to combine iteration value in foreach loop to a getmethod name

Tags: java, jstl, jstl-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzQoW.png)

Here, I am trying to print 10 labels using getter methods there are 10 getter methods in my bean class named as getLabel1(),getLabel2().......getLabel10().
instead of writing these 10 getter methods, I am using here foreach loop in jstl
for each iteration i am combining the iteration value  to getMethod name. I am also trying like this

${labelsBean.getLabel+""+${i}+""+()}
and
${labelsBean.getLabel+${i}+()}
and
${labelsBean.getLabel${i}()}
and

                ${labels.label[i]}

not working all above can you please  give me a suggestion to solve this error

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve? Do you want to combine values of 10 fields into single string and display in your JSP? You don't need to access the getter method directly in jstl. use your field name instead like `labelsBean.label1`

Comment: Please don't tag spam.

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160970/how-do-i-invoke-a-java-method-when-given-the-method-name-as-a-string

Comment: This question has a bad smell. You should probably store your labels in a list instead of having a separate method for each.